# Refrigerator trips One GFI, but not Another GFI

Tags: refrigerator

I've had refrigerator plugged into a GFI for over a year in the garage. Recently it's tripped the GFI, so I thought the

Comment: You need to complete your question.

Comment: The breaker must have tripped mid thought... :D  Click the [edit] button to finish your thought.

Comment: What make and model are the two GFCIs in question?